# there is an error when I am trying to execute a node js app: findById is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

There is a error:

> `findById` is not a function

when I'm trying to execute a node js app.
This is my code, exclusively for the eCommerce website.

```
const path = require('path');

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const errorController = require('./controllers/error');
const sequelize = require('./util/database');
const Product = require('./models/product');
const User = require('./models/user');

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', 'views');

const adminRoutes = require('./routes/admin');
const shopRoutes = require('./routes/shop');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

//findById methode

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  User.findById(1)
      .then(user => {
        req.user = user;
        next();
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

//routes controller

```
app.use('/admin', adminRoutes);
app.use(shopRoutes);

app.use(errorController.get404);

Product.belongsTo(User, { constraints: true, onDelete: 'CASCADE' });
User.hasMany(Product);
```

//sequelize statements

```
sequelize
  // .sync({ force: true })
  .sync()
  .then(result => {
    return User.findById(1);
    // console.log(result);
  })
  .then(user => {
    if (!user) {
      return User.create({ name: 'Max', email: 'test@test.com' });
    }
    return User;
  })
  .then(user => {
    // console.log(user);
```

//port configuration

```
  app.listen(3000,() => console.log(`looking at local host port number 3000`));
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: we need to see the user model

Answer (score 0):

This error means that findById is not defined in your user model. You'll need to add and export this method in your './models/user' module.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the Model method [findByPk](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findByPk) to "Search for a single instance by its primary key.")  Try:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  User.findByPk(1)
    .then(user => {
```